# Control.DataBindings.Add breaks with period in data member name

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, data-binding

I am trying to add to a binding using Control.DataBindings.Add(). The issue that I am having is that the data member name has a period and space in it("Foo. Bar"). When I try to add the binding I pass in the string "Foo. Bar" as one of the arguments and I get an exception "CAnnot find datamember "Foo.".

Is there a syntax that I need to use to pass the datamember name in when it has a period in it? I tried adding "[]" around the name but no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you manage to have member name with space in it?

Comment: The bindingSource.Datasource is a DataView. One of the columns in the Table parameter of the DataView has a name with a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging around to find a solution to this problem I discovered that if you make your DataSource a collection (even of one item) the .Net 4.0 implmentation will work....

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

list.Add(myDataSource);

Binding binding = new Binding(PropertyName, list, "Dotted.Path.Name");

Control.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
Control.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ds,"Foo. Bar"));
```

Comment: Still get an exception using that.

Comment: could you debug and check the DataView Columns and see whats the Name for the one you have problem with

Comment: Yes, If I look at the ctype(mBindingSource.DataSource, DataView).Table.Columns(9).ColumnName it is "Foo. Bar".

Comment: A little more information.

 

I now create a Binding object before hand with this line

 

Dim Binding As New Binding("Value", BindingSource, "Foo. Bar") 

 

Then I try to bind the field using Control.DataBindings.Add(Binding)

It fails. Interestingly if I look at the Binding.BindingMemberInfo Here is what I see:

    BindingField: " Bar"

    BindingMember: "Foo. Bar"

    BindingPath: "Foo"

 

I need the binding path to read "Foo. Bar"

Answer (score 0):

This should just work, since I have been doing that with .Net 2.0 for years. Only I would not have a space after the decimal. However, it seems that .Net 4.0 is treating this differently under some circumstances. I get the same Argument error as you did especially when the bound control resides inside a user control (but not always...)

Funny enough when running the same code in Net 3.5 (or 2.0) it behaves as expected and I can just use `CheckBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked",obj,"MainBooking.JoinersAllowed")`. But in Net 4.0 it is giving me lots of grief. Any solutions/suggestions would be welcome.